# Why wont my Void Main run my public static int[] C#

Tags: c#

[image]I'm having a hard time understanding why my method will not execute in my void Main. I have an array for the parameter but it will not execute.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TwoSums([2, 7, 11, 15],9); //Error is here.
        }

        public static int [] TwoSums(int[] nums, int target)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <nums.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = i+1; i< nums.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target) 
                    return new int[]
                     {
                        i,j
                     };
                }
            }
            return Array.Empty<int>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you read and show us the error message you are getting?

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, **why not**?

Comment: If the code actually runs fine, youre not **doing** anything with the returned `TwoSums()` array

Comment: You don't use square brackets to create an array. You create one correctly below. Have you tried `new int[] {2, 7, 11, 15} `?

Comment: Just posted a picture. I apologize, I am still new to coding so I have not used debugger and will use it now and moving forward.

Comment: That error isn't from the debugger btw, it's a compile time error. If the source didn't compile, then there is no program to run or debug. I guess you're used to Python though, so various things may take some getting used to.

Comment: Did you mix up syntax with JavaScript?

Comment: I'm used to JavaScript and I'm trying to learn C# right now. I'm not an expert in JavaScript, but I am learning the differences.

Comment: Well, your problem right now is that the syntax to declare an array in C# is different from that in JavaScript, and since C# is compiled rather than interpreted like JS is, then you get the error immediately when you compile it, before your program even has a chance to run.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you gave, you should be getting errors similar to the following:

> Compilation error (line 7, col 11): Invalid expression term '[' 
> Compilation error (line 7, col 12): ) expected 
> Compilation error (line 7, col 13): ; expected 
> Compilation error (line 7, col 13): Invalid expression term ','
> Compilation error (line 7, col 15): ; expected
> ... more errors ...

When you look at the line `TwoSums([2, 7, 11, 15],9);` what is `[2, 7, 11, 15]` in the context of this usage? You want it to be an array, you know it's an array, but the compiler doesn't know it's an array. You have to define your arrays in some way to let the system know, "Oh, hey, this is an array". For example, `TwoSums( new [] { 2, 7, 11, 15 }, 9);` might be worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

Some errors in your codes, so I provide a tested version:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] x;
        int[] nums = new int[]{2, 7, 11, 15};

        x = TwoSums(nums, 9);
        
        foreach (int i in x)
        {
            System.Console.Write("{0} ", i);
        }
    }

    public static int[] TwoSums(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; i < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                    return new int[]{i, j};
            }
        }

        return Array.Empty<int>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the "new int[] {1,2,3,4}"

This will complile (just tested):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TwoSums(new [] { 2, 7, 11, 15}, 9); //No error here anymore  :)
    }

    public static int[] TwoSums(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; i < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                    return new int[]
                     {
                    i,j
                     };
            }
        }
        return Array.Empty<int>();
    }
}
```